# Autolayout detect when UIView got the frame

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have `UIView` that has auto layout constraints. I create it with frame `CGRectZero`. So I don't the real size. It will depend on superview.

But I want to know when my view get a frame that I can use for my calculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you shouldn't really need to know anything about the frame. Although if you did need to know, you could just implement `-layoutSubviews` in your view, or `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` at the view controller level.

Here after calling `super` the frames should be set to what AutoLayout resolved them to be.

Also good practise to take on board is #7 of the following post: [Forget frame](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/).

I also highly recommend reading about the AutoLayout process [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html).

Comment: ok I have a view A that contains another view B. And view B has image. everything is based on auto-layout. Then seems I need to subcalsing UIView B to perform -layouts subviews? Because I am interested in image that is part of view B. and I need to add top corner radius to image view via CALayer.

Comment: If all you need to do is add a corner radius to your image view, then you don't need to worry about frames, just do that in view A's awakeFromNib, or in it's initWithFrame:. If you've got a complete storyboard setup and none of your views are custom UIView subclasses, then you could just add an outlet from view B to your view controller and inside of viewDidLoad set the corner radius.

Comment: Although how are you going to deal with layer changes if you forget frames? What about the times when you are dealing with `CGRect` values, not necessarily directly connected to a view?

Comment: generally you might not need to know the frame, but in my case, I have a template image which I want to set a background color for, and want to calculate the radius so it masks as a circle behind the circular image.  Thus, I need to know the frame for the image view and hardcoding it feels dirty.

However, layoutSubviews does not seem to work for me.  (it is in a UITableViewCell subclass, and the imageview is a circular accessory view)